# How to match on unknown generic type without warnings

Tags: scala, generics, types, pattern-matching, unchecked-cast

I have a function that might receive input of any Java/Scala type as argument:

```
def foo(arbitraryInput: Object): Option[Object] = {
    arbitraryInput match {
        case map: Map[Object, Object] => map.get("foo")
        // ...
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the `: Map[Object, Object]`-pattern:

- If I say `case map : Map[Object, Object]`, I get a warning that `non-variable type argument is unchecked`.
- If I say `case map : Map[_, _]`, I get an error on `map.get`, indicating the compiler found type `_`, but was looking for `Object`.
- If I say `case map : Map` the compiler complains that Map needs type arguments

Is it possible to match like this and tell the compiler "hey, I know the type info is lost at runtime, `Object` is fine, just give me `Map[Any, Any]`"?

Comment: Accept and return `Any`, there is no point in using `Object`

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/eHQWIevLTX6NLc2645zBNQ

Comment: You can also add `@uncheked` annotation to make the compiler stop worrying: `case map: Map[Any @unchecked, _] => map.get("foo")`

Comment: nice something like @unchecked was the goal. Like "please Mr.Compiler trust me"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `@unchecked` annotation to some of the type arguments:

```
def test(data: Any): Option[Any] = data match {
  case map: Map[Any @unchecked, _] => map.get("foo")
  case _ => None
}
```